# Using ListSFTP and FETCHFTP to process a file with a condition

Tags: list, fetch, apache-nifi

I am a begginer and I've to List two files (a.xlsx and mark.txt) in a SFTP, fetching them and only process it when i've both files,

This is the logic:

1. If i have "mark.txt" i process a.xlsx and i delete "mark.txt".
2. For the next start, when i don't have "mark.txt" i don't process anything.
3. If i have again "mark.txt" i process a.xlsx and i delete "mark.txt".
4. Repeat.

I've tried with ListSFTP, then FetchSFTP, and then use a RouteonAttribute, but i don't know how to solve it.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is look for the file a.xlsx and then process it if found. When NiFi picks up this file, it can delete it so the next time it looks for the xlsx file, it will be a new one. Therefore, if the file isn’t found, then it won’t do anything. Looking for the .txt and then pulling the .xlsx isn’t the best way to do this, just pull the XLSX directly.

One way to do what you’re asking is to look for mark.txt and if found, then you can write a script using a language like Python to get the file, instead of having to write a NiFi processor. This would be something like List File -> ExecuteStreamCommand where the ExecuteStreamCommand would be a Python script.